# Unable to rename files recursively using xargs command

Tags: unix, xargs

I have to rename all the files recursively which match the pattern. I am using the below command.

`find . -type f -iname 'dev*' | xargs -I{}  mv $1 echo '/dev-profile/prod-profile'`

When i run the above command, I am getting the below error
`missing destination file operand after /dev-profile/prod-profile`

I need to replace all the files recursively. Where I am going wrong.

Comment: Explain in words what you expect your code to do. Provide some sample expected source paths and their corresponding destination path. Then we can explain how best to sort out your code.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with arguments in `xargs` often goes into a mess with `bash -c ... _`.

If you have GNU Parallel you avoid this mess and can probably do something like this:

```
find . -type f -iname 'dev*' | parallel mv {} /dev-profile/prod-profile
```